# List stores the last added value only

Tags: java

I have a problem with the following code:

First of all i have an inner class:

```
public class TraceMessage{
        private String messageType;
        private String tracedIdentifier;
        private List<String> content;



        TraceMessage(){
            content = new ArrayList<String>();
            messageType="";
            tracedIdentifier="";
        }

        TraceMessage(String messageType, String identifier ,List<String> content){
            this.messageType = messageType;
            this.tracedIdentifier = identifier;   
            this.content = content;
        }
```

It has getters and setter for the 3 attribute. My problem is:

I have a list of this messages:

```
private List<TraceMessage> messages = new ArrayList<TraceMessage>();
```

and I'm trying to add new elements to this like that:

```
messages.add(new TraceMessage(temp.messageType,temp.tracedIdentifier,temp.content));
```

where temp is an TraceMessage object.

So My problem when i add a message type object like that to the List the values are fine I even put printout to the Constructor and it has also shows the good value. But later When I'm trying to use that List all elements of the list has the same content(the last one). What could be the problem?

Here is the full part where i add the messages:

```
String fileName="tracefile.MTR";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {   
            String line;
            TraceMessage temp = new TraceMessage();
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("MSCi")){
                     temp.content.clear();
                     temp.content.add(line);
                }
                else if(line.contains("CALL PHASE")){
                     temp.messageType = line.substring(60);
                     temp.content.add(line);
                }

                else if(line.contains("CALL ID")){
                     temp.tracedIdentifier = line.substring(22);
                     temp.content.add(line);
                }
                else if(line.contains("END OF REPORT")){
                    temp.content.add(line); 
                    messages.add(new TraceMessage(temp.messageType,temp.tracedIdentifier,temp.content));          
                }
                else{
                    temp.content.add(line);
                }


            }   

        } finally {
            br.close();



        }
```

Comment: If `temp` is already a `TraceMessage` object, why don't you add it directly to your `messages` list?: `messages.add(temp)`

Comment: The problem is likely to be you are not showing us the real code here and you are actually adding the same object multiple times.  Can you show us a self contained test which reproduces the problem?

Comment: you are always getting same object temp.

Comment: @maqjav I suspect that is actually the problem.

Comment: I added the code part you asked for. Content doesnt have the same value when I add it I am sure I print it out before adding and it shows the corret value

Comment: If I'm trying to add the temp it has the same values for all attributes not just the List but the 2 Strings too

Comment: Examining `messages.size ()` might be useful.  If that is increasing,  messages *are* being added to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the second constructor to take copy of list

```
TraceMessage(String messageType, String identifier ,List<String> content){
    this.messageType = messageType;
    this.tracedIdentifier = identifier;   
    this.content = new ArrayList<String>(content);
}
```

This will copy `temp.content` that you are reusing in `while` loop. Instances will be safe from operations on contents collection executed outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

put `TraceMessage temp = new TraceMessage();`
inside the while loop

and change `messages.add(new TraceMessage(temp.messageType,temp.tracedIdentifier,temp.content));`

to

`messages.add(temp);`

Ok if you can't do that

replace `messages.add(new TraceMessage(temp.messageType,temp.tracedIdentifier,temp.content));`
with 
`messages.add(temp); messages = new TraceMessage();`

Comment: I can't really put it in the loop because if I put it in one of the blocks (if/else) the other blocks cant see it

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
...
try {   
    String line;

    List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    String messageType = "";
    String tracedIdentifier = "";

    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("MSCi")){
            content.clear();
            content.add(line);
        }
        else if (line.contains("CALL PHASE")) {
            messageType = line.substring(60);
            content.add(line);
        }
        else if (line.contains("CALL ID")) {
            tracedIdentifier = line.substring(22);
            content.add(line);
        }
        else if (line.contains("END OF REPORT")) {
            content.add(line); 
            messages.add(new TraceMessage(messageType, tracedIdentifier, content);          
        }
        else {
            content.add(line);
        }
    }   
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Instead of using a `temp` object, save your attributes in external variables (out of the while loop) and then add a new object to your `messages` list with those variables.